# Move text from left to right using jquery slide scroller

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I have this script for scrolling text.

```
window.requestAnimationFrame = (function(){
            return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
                    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
                    function( callback ){
                        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
                    };
        })();

        var speed = 6000;
        (function currencySlide(){
            var currencyPairWidth = $('.slideItem:first-child').outerWidth();
            $(".slideContainer").animate({marginLeft:-currencyPairWidth},speed, 'linear', function(){
                $(this).css({marginLeft:0}).find("li:last").after($(this).find("li:first"));
            });
            requestAnimationFrame(currencySlide);
        })();
```

**HTML**

```
<div class='slider'>
            <div class="edge"></div>
            <ul class="slideContainer" id="money_start">
            <li class="slideItem">
             <span>Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus</span>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

**Problem:** It is scrolling text from right to left, but I want to scroll text from left to right.
Help me with any best solution.

Comment: Not able to visualise, Please post corresponding html

Comment: I add corresponding html also

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this? It seems more easier.

```js
$('.slideItem').animate({right: 0}, 1000);
$('.slideItem').animate({left: 0}, 1000);
```

```css
.slideItem {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slideItem">TEXT</div>
```

Comment: this code just move from left to right, I need continuously like marque, but with no gap.

Comment: Could you share jsfiddle or plunker?

Answer (score 0):

few lines changed and the animation happens from left to right(as you asked for).

```js
window.requestAnimationFrame = (function () {
        return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
                window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
                function (callback) {
                    window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
                };
    })();

            var speed = 600;
    (function currencySlide() {
        var currencyPairWidth = $('.slideItem:first-child').outerWidth();
        $(".slideContainer").css("marginLeft", -currencyPairWidth + 500);//Added this line
        $(".slideContainer").animate({ marginLeft: 75 }, speed, 'linear');
        requestAnimationFrame(currencySlide);
    })();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='slider'>
        <div class="edge">
        </div>
        <ul class="slideContainer" id="money_start">
            <li class="slideItem"><span>Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```